# How do you use UIWebview to make a transaction using Paypal and retrieve a receipt or transaction information.

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, payment, paypal

I've seen different documentation on various forums and site on different ways of using Paypal api,  here is a pretty useful link: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECOnMobileDevices&bn_r=o/, My question is a little different i do not want to use any of the Paypal libraries offered to us in my app, this is the link to libraries:https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/sdk , I also do not want to gather any personal information, I want Paypal to take care of everything. So in other words I want to be able to open up a UIWebview to the Paypal's mobile site if possible (or if not the regular site will work) have to user log in with his credential or he can use the express checkout option and get back the transaction ID, or receipt what ever is available. I'm a little new to iOS and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use any libraries or API's, Express Checkout won't work for you.
Which does make it somewhat easier, as you can just use PayPal Website Payments Standard in a UIWebView instead.

For example; just open https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=your@email.tld&amount=1.99&currency_code=GBP

This will start a 1.99 GBP payment to email@here.tld via PayPal, and automatically use a mobile layout.

If you subsequently want to receive transaction information; set up PayPal IPN on your account and use that to receive transaction-related events. This can be handled outside your app, and thus take away precious processing power to the server.
For an overview on getting started with PayPal IPN, have a look at https://www.paypal.com/ipn/

Comment: <no clue about ipn>I'm not familiar with this framework, but this seems fragile to place the price in the URL.  Couldn't someone do URL tampering with the request to edit the price to say 0.01? </no clue about ipn>

Comment: Yes, they could. IPN will send a POST back to you server, including the amount paid. If this amount differs from the amount you expected, you can void / refund the transaction. But you're absolutely right; it's not the most elegant solution. It is the easiest one, though.

Comment: I have used above method but page is not responsive... have you any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest against trying to do transactions through paypal.  If you look at the App Store Review Guidelines it states that

```
11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected
```

Comment: I won't run into the app store issue since I have an enterprise license and will distribute my app through the app store.

Comment: Sorry! I meant will not distribute the app through the app store